# why model is not display as given in document?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

i saw this document 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal

I tried to implement this but it not show any thing why ?
it is not giving any error also
here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/aRPfONa55Cn7GTCItDbH?p=preview 
**update**

https://plnkr.co/edit/aRPfONa55Cn7GTCItDbH?p=preview

```js
const  Modal  = ReactModal;
class Main extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { modalIsOpen: false };
  }
 function closeModal() {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
  }
  function afterOpenModal() {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
  }
   function openModal() {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
  }
  render() {
    return  (
       <div>
        <button onClick={this.openModal}>Open Modal</button>
        <Modal
          isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
          onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal}
          onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
          style={customStyles}
          contentLabel="Example Modal"
        >

          <h2 ref="subtitle">Hello</h2>
          <button onClick={this.closeModal}>close</button>
          <div>I am a modal</div>
          <form>
            <input />
            <button>tab navigation</button>
            <button>stays</button>
            <button>inside</button>
            <button>the modal</button>
          </form>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Main/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, Problem is that you are never setting your `modalIsOpen` state variable to true.

```
<button onClick={this.openModal}>Open Modal</button>
```

When user clicks on the above button, you are calling  `openModal` function. Inside which you need to set `modalIsOpen` to true.

```
function openModal() {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: true});
}
```

And, I also think that you'll need to change your `afterOpenModal` function as it will set `modalIsOpen` to false immediately once the modal opens. So you can just comment out that code, if not needed and At last `onRequestClose` you are calling `closeModal` function which will set the state variable `modalIsOpen` to false and modal will be hidden from the view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your methods otherwise React will not find them.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { modalIsOpen: false };
    this.closeModal.bind(this); //etc.
  }
```

Alternatively you don't need to do that if you support ES6 and use the `=>` key e.g.

```
 function closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
  }
```

The React docu about [handling events](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: see update plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/aRPfONa55Cn7GTCItDbH?p=preview